# Kalman filter without model versus RLS

Tags: kalman-filters, adaptive-filters

As I found out in my previous question [Where to get transtion matrix for Kalman filter?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/34069/19697), I need a model for correct usage of Kalman filter.

In paper [On the Intrinsic Relationship Between the Least Mean Square and Kalman Filters](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7298563/?arnumber=7298563&tag=1) there is model-less Kalman filter - The Kalman filter for deterministic states:

\begin{align}
\textbf{g}(k) &= \textbf{P}(k)\textbf{x}(k) / (\textbf{x}^T(k)\textbf{P}(k)\textbf{x}(k) + r)\\
y(k) &= \textbf{x}^T(k)\textbf{w}(k)\\
e(k) &= d(k) - y(k)\\
\textbf{w}(k) &= \textbf{w}(k-1) + \textbf{g}(k)e(k)\\
\textbf{P}(k) &= \textbf{P}(k-1) - \textbf{g}(k)\textbf{x}(k)\textbf{P}(k-1)
\end{align}

where $\textbf{g}(k)$ is gain vector $\textbf{P}(k)$ is covariance matrix, $e(k)$ is error, $\textbf{w}(k)$ adaptive filter weights and $\textbf{x}(k)$ are inputs (not really a states here), $d(k)$ is target, $y(k)$ is filter output.

Nice thing is that $\textbf{x}^T(k)\textbf{P}(k)\textbf{x}(k)$ is scalar, so no matrix inversion is needed.

- What is difference of this in comparison with RLS filter?
- What should be better?
- Is it case specific or is there some obvious difference what I am missing?
- Is it even a good idea to use this Kalman filter over RLS or NLMS?